# Installing graphics card in laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have Acer Aspire 5740 laptop. The version I have do not have ATI dedicated graphics card. Now I wish to install a graphics card in my laptop. Can it be done? If not then what are other alternative (other then buying a new one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, in laptops you can never install any "card" ( only if it's an PCMCIA card).
Sorry , but you just can't.

Comment: There are some external options you could look at (especially if it has a good ExpressCard controller) but odds are they're all way more expensive than simply buying a better machine.